# Auto Sort files from one folder to another

Tags: windows, batch

I am looking to create a folder that whenever a file(s) is placed into it, a batch file is triggered to properly place the file(s) in the correct folder(s) based on aspects of the filename (similar to the auto sort folder for iTunes).

The files will always be named in the following manner:

- `123456 19900101 Information.pdf`.
- The first 6 digits are the unique identifier to the Parent folder in which the File(s) will be moved to.
- Then the information block will determine which sub folder the file(s) will be stored into the parent folder.

Graphic example of folder structure where file(s) will be sent:

[image]

I know there is the `move` and `xcopy` commands but I haven't come across a way for the code to determine the filename and use parts of it to determine the path location for the file(s) to be moved into.

Comment: Related: [Batch move files to new subfolders based on name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29260844/3439404) or [more alike tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch-file+move+files+to+subfolders)